# Replacing/deploying only the changes in the already depolyed ear in Jboss 7

Tags: maven, jboss7.x

I am deploying the ear file each time when i making a changes as my project is multi-module and it is really tedious to upload/deployed the entire ear again in Jboss 7.Is there any way to replace only the changed jar/war/files in the already deployed ear in jboss without deploying the entire ear file again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using JRebel - it allows reloading changes. After you compile any class it will automaticaly reload it, supporting modern frameworks (like reloading spring beans, etc) and application servers (JBoss included). It works as a java agent. You will find more details on producent site: http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/features/

To introduce JRebel in Maven project you just need to add jrebel-maven-plugin

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But my concern is that there is already an ear deployed in the testing server(Jboss7).Simultaneously i making changes to the module and i want to load only the changed stuff in my already deployed ear instead of building my ear and redeploying.

Comment: That's exactly what Jebel do :-) You just compile changed class from IDE and only this class will be reloaded in deployed ear. Without building new ear and redeploying